# Saving a list with different data types

Tags: r, list

I want to save a list of lists in R so I can come back to it later.

The list contains multiple lists which in turn contain a tidymodel (linear regression lm), 2 Tibbles, and a ggplot.

[image: structure of my list]

I don't mind how it's stored I just want to make sure I don't lose it when I tidy my work environment.

Comment: Use `saveRDS()` and `readRDS()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `saveRDS()` and `readRDS()` for lists or any other R objects.

```r
# list
l = list(iris,
         'string',
         lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris),
         TRUE)
# path
fl = file.path(tempdir(), 'file.rds')
# save & read
saveRDS(l, fl)
readRDS(fl)
```